# Content Type Policy Statement not appearing

Tags: content-type, information-policy

I've created a content type and am trying to configure Policy Statement under Information Management Policy Settings.

You are meant to enter the policy statement in a multi-line text box.  The description reads:

> The policy statement is displayed to end users when they open items
>   subject to this policy. etc, etc.

I've published the Content Type.  I open the document and nothing appears?  Is the Policy Statement meant to be a popup window or something?

I'm using SharePoint Online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this.  Per Microsoft:

> Note:  Information management policies are compiled by an Information
>   Management Policy Timer Job, managed by Microsoft, which runs weekly.
>   Therefore, your policies may not take effect immediately. The
>   frequency and date of the Information Management Policy Timer Job
>   cannot be changed.

The reference came from [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-apply-information-management-policies-EB501FE9-2EF6-4150-945A-65A6451EE9E9)